# Jcenter inclsuion: The version control <url> returns 404, worked before

Tags: artifactory, bintray, jcenter

I have these two packages:

https://bintray.com/beta/#/stoyicker/test-accessors/annotations?tab=overview
https://bintray.com/beta/#/stoyicker/test-accessors/processor-java?tab=overview

The former is, as you can see, included in Jcenter. I made a request and got approved within a day. However, for the second one, I cannot make a request because I get met with a dialog stating "The version control  returns 404" for its vcs url. Ironic, because the first one has the exact same url and I never saw this problem with it.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this a 'bug'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sound and looks of it you should be using `https` and not `ssh` as the link for your `vsc` link.
If that doesn't work then I would contact support.

Comment: This did the trick. I still don't understand why it worked for the previous project though, but at least I can move forward. Thanks!